# Why can't I ask questions on Super User?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

First of all, I posted here because I don't have enough points to post on Meta Super User.

I am trying to post a question, but I keep getting a message that questions from my account are no longer accepted.

Why is this? I have only asked three questions and two of them don't have any votes and only one has been downvoted. Did my account get suspended because of just one negative vote? I don't think that is how this site works.

Even if that is the reason, I should still be allowed to ask a new question as the last question I asked was 6 months ago on the 6th of June.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: The last question you asked was 30th june https://superuser.com/questions/1454532/for-security-purposes-can-i-use-vpn-with-ufw-to-allow-traffic-only-from-the-vpn

Answer (score 4):

You also have 8 deleted questions with downvotes, which count against the limit. Its automatic, and there's not much that can be done about it.

Comment: Don't they count towards the limit?

Comment: Yes they do. But its not 'just' three questions.

Comment: Can you tell me where can I see the deleted questions? I can't find them.

Comment: @Linux_user0987, go to the Activity tab of your profile and select the Questions tab.  At the bottom is a text button, "deleted recent questions".  That will show questions that were deleted in the recent past (I think "recent" includes a few months, if I remember right).

Comment: Is there any way to see questions older than a few months? I can't remember getting 8 questions deleted.